# Blender 4.0 - viewport control buttons disappeared

Tags: 3d-view, interface

The first image is my Blender:

[image: No buttons - my Blender]

And I need those viewport control buttons on the second image:

[image: The buttons I need]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that *Show Gizmos* is enabled:

[image]

Comment: Those are the overlays, the gizmos are to the left of that. Also it's already enabled in the screenshots :)

Comment: TYYYY I FOUND IT!

Comment: @Geri As she said, the second screenshot is not hers   ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, here, an upvote ;)

Comment: @Geri oops sorry i thought it was you  ;)

Comment: No matter if you enable the _Overlays_ or not, what @Geri said is legitimate: they do not enable the gizmos - see your own screenshot: the overlays are disabled, but the gizmos are visible. But if _Show Gizmos_ is disabled, you can enable the overlays as much as you want, the gizmos won't show. Well, Daniela found it so who cares... but maybe future users are not so canny.

Comment: Sorry i still don't get it, the screenshot shows that the gizmos are disabled, the solution was to enable them back, what do ypu mean by "they do not enable the gizmos?" Maybe give your own answer to make it more understandable?

Comment: @moonboots You just marked the wrong button in your image. The viewport controls marked in the question's second screenshot which are missing in the first, are enabled by the _Show Gizmo_ button, the one that looks like bow and arrow left of the _Show Overlays_ button (the one you marked and incorrectly called _Viewport Gizmos_).

Comment: Oh of course thanks   ;)